# Cuda streams synchronization issue with cupy and tensorRT

Tags: stream, synchronization, tensorrt, cupy

I am working with TensorRT and cupy. The following code does not wait for the cuda calls too be executed if I set the `cp.cuda.Stream(non_blocking=True)` while it works perfectly with `non_blocking=False`.
Why shouldn't it work with `non_blocking=True`? I checked the input data and it is fine. But the code ends up with my model returning random detections (random data), meaning that there are some synchronization issues.

```
        # Select stream
        stream.use()
        # Copy cupy array to the buffer
        input_images = cp.array(batch_input_image)
        cp.copyto(cuda_inputs[0], input_images)
        # Run inference.
        context.execute_async(bindings=bindings, stream_handle=stream.ptr, batch_size=len(batch_input_image))
        # Copy results from the buffer
        output_images = cuda_outputs[0].copy()
        # Split results into batch
        list_output = cp.split(output_images, indices_or_sections=len(batch_input_image), axis=0)
        # Squeeze output arrays to remove axis of length one
        list_output = [cp.squeeze(array) for array in list_output]
        # Synchronize the stream
        stream.synchronize()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with cupy, but generally in CUDA this flag means that the stream is synchronizing with the "main" stream. So if some of the operations run on the main stream, and some - on another, the different behavior based on the flag makes sense.

Comment: This is likely an issue of TensorRT and/or `bindings` as discussed in: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/6104

Answer (score 0):

After receiving some support from Nvidia, I can confirm this was not a `cupy` issue. It seems to be a problem with the C++ code of the TensorRT model, as discussed here: github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/6104 .